# How to access method in double pointer object

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, object, pointers

I have simple example code

```
class Child2{
    public:
    Child2(){
        cout<<"this is child2"<<endl;
    }

    void test2(){
        cout<<"Method Child 2"<<endl;
    }
};
class Child1{
    public:
    Child2 **child2;
    Child1(){
        child2 = new Child2 *[1];
        child2[0] = new Child2();
        cout<<"this is child1"<<endl;
    }
    void test1(){
        cout<<"Method Child 1"<<endl;
    }
};
class Top{
    public:
    Child1 **child1;

    Top(){
        child1 = new Child1 *[2];
        child1[0] = new Child1();
        child1[1] = new Child1();
        cout<<"this is top"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Now, I know i can access method "test2()" by using

```
top->child1[0]->child2[0]->test2();
```

But is there any way if i want to access the method dynamically without to put index of array so "test2()" from all "child2" can be accessed . I need to keep the double pointer because i want to assign the object during the runtime using input.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator that will magically invoke the method for all elements of the array.

The easiest way would be to use a loop over each item in the array:

```
for(int ndx = 0, count = ...; count != ndx; ++ndx)
  child2[ndx]->test();
```

You could also use std::for_each, but honestly for cases this trivial I find the explicit loop far more readable, that is it is more immediately apparent to me what is being done.

Comment: Or even better, use `std::vector` and range based loop (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).